# Parsing nested json in sparksql

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this nested schema format in `JavaSchemaRDD`

```
   root
   |-- ProductInfo: struct (nullable = true)
   |    |-- Features: string (nullable = true)
   |    |-- ImgURL: string (nullable = true)
   |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
   |    |-- Price: string (nullable = true)
   |    |-- ProductID: string (nullable = true)
   |-- Reviews: array (nullable = true)
   |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
   |    |    |-- Author: string (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- Content: string (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- Overall: string (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- ReviewID: string (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- Title: string (nullable = true)
   |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to select Name of the product based on the Overall rating of the product.

I wrote as below

```
JavaSchemaRDD variable = sqlContext.sql("SELECT ProductInfo.Name FROM Table" + "WHERE Reviews.element.Overall=5.0" + "ORDER BY c");
```

But it seems there is a mistake.

What would be the write one?

Comment: What are you ordering by c?
Here is what you should be doing 
val variable = sqlContext.sql("SELECT ProductInfo.Name,Reviews.Overall as rating FROM Table" + "WHERE rating=5.0");